# Compiler Issues Whn Building Native Quarkus Apllication

Tags: java, c++, windows, quarkus, graalvm

Im trying to build a native quarkus application but getting issues with the windows compiler. I have installed visual studio build tools. Initially the build couldnt find cl.exe so I had to add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x64 to my path variable. I had tried to use the VCvars bat file as suggested in some answers on here but that didnt seem to make any difference to my environment vars.

Now when building (in eclipse using the bundled maven) im receiving the following error:

```
Error: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c). Compiler command ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe' /WX /W4 /wd4244 /wd4245 /wd4800 /wd4804 /wd4214 '/FeC:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.exe' 'C:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c' ' output included error: [AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c, C:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c(1): fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set]
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c). Compiler command ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe' /WX /W4 /wd4244 /wd4245 /wd4800 /wd4804 /wd4214 '/FeC:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.exe' 'C:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c' ' output included error: [AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c, C:\Users\lukeg\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-9347802898847780383\AArch64LibCHelperDirectives.c(1): fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set]
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:139)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.NativeLibraries.reportErrors(NativeLibraries.java:369)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.processNativeLibraryImports(NativeImageGenerator.java:1585)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeLibraries(NativeImageGenerator.java:1064)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:882)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:561)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:476)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Is there anything else im missing here? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does the `INCLUDE` environment variable point to when the command-line compiler is run?  If not that, then the `/I` command-line compiler option has to be used to point to the include directory.